# Converting a .cptx file to an .swf file

Tags: file, flash, adobe-captivate

I have a college project and I have a presentation almost done using adobe captivate. It saved as a .cptx file. My lecturer left a message online saying that it has to be an .swf file. There is no option on captivate to convert it to an .swf. When I export it to flash and play it, it is completely blank and none of my work appears.

Any ideas as to how I can convert my .cptx to .swf? (With the presentation coming out as it did on captivate)

Thanks.

Comment: There should be an Export or Publish as SWF option in Captivate.

Comment: yup thats sorted thanks very much mate

Answer (score 0):

To convert a cptx file to a SWF you need to 'publish' your project. Go to File > Publish and choose the SWF option (this may be different depending on which version of Captivate you're using).

Hope this helps.

-Sean